# DiscreteDelta, DiscreteConvolve, PiecewiseExpand: odd behavior

Tags: simplifying-expressions, piecewise, convolution

I noticed something odd when trying `DiscreteDelta`, `DiscreteConvolve` and `PiecewiseExpand` for the first time. Running

```
f = PiecewiseExpand[Sum[(1/4) DiscreteDelta[n - i], {i, 1, 4}]];
f2 = PiecewiseExpand[DiscreteConvolve[f, f, n, m] /. {m -> n}];
f3 = PiecewiseExpand[(DiscreteConvolve[f, f2, n, m]) /. {m -> n}]
```

returns

[image]

which is not expected. However, running

```
f = Sum[(1/4) DiscreteDelta[n - i], {i, 1, 4}];
f2 = DiscreteConvolve[f, f, n, m] /. {m -> n};
f3 = PiecewiseExpand[(DiscreteConvolve[f, f2, n, m]) /. {m -> n}]
```

returns

[image]

which is what I expected to see.

Is this the expected behavior? Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to exclude piecewise expansion from `Simplify`?

This was observed on Mathematica 13.3.1.0.